# May I ask professors to reschedule two back to back night classes from 4:30PM to 9:00PM?

Tags: graduate-school, professorship

As a graduate school student, I have two professors teaching two separate classes that go from 4:30PM to 5:50pm and 6:00pm to 9:00PM. This happens every one day of the week.

I'm not sure whether I can handle concentrating for 5 hours and I have the option to not take a class but it would delay graduating by a semester.

Do I negotiate with the professor to reschedule or do they have the power to deny it?

Comment: Do a lot of people in your dept have the same problem?

Comment: You can ask, but I don't see success. You aren't the only student.

Comment: I think a lot of students enrolled in evening-only programs have similar schedule issues. Some MS programs are like that so that working people can earn a degree.

Comment: I just decided to take classes I’m interested in and this semester is a unique combination of evening classes

Comment: They definitely "have the power to deny it." But it never hurts to ask (especially if there are more students in your shoes, as @Azor indicates).

Comment: Yes, certainly ask (not "negotiate"). Especially for small graduate classes, it might well be possible to change the time. If not, then nothing lost.

Comment: Usually there is a very compelling reason for such strange hours, so I would not be hopeful of a rescheduling. It's probably way too late to do anything about it anyway. Ideally the schedules should be announced well in advance, but many administrators are reluctant to publish "tentative schedules". Teachers (and the poor junior colleague who got the short straw and is in charge of compiling the schedule for the department) would be open to that, but I am not holding my breath even though getting student feedback on tentative schedules would be optimal.

Comment: @GregMartin's point is a good one.  I have managed to completely reschedule classes with something like 5–6 students in them in the past.  For classes much larger than that, though, there's rarely another time when everyone is available.

Comment: _This happens every one day of the week_ - Do you mean "happens once each week", or 5 or 7 times each week?

Comment: @ Azor Ahai -him-: But for all we know, those hours might have been requested by other students or the instructor, for instance to keep them from having to make extra trips to campus.

Comment: Don't forget that if you **do** propose reschedule, please - if possible - come up with the alternative time yourself. That makes the rescheduling easier for everyone involved. For perspective, my department has one place where all schedules on resources availability (room, teacher, special equipment, etc.) can be found, so such thing is usually doable. YMMV, though.

Comment: @Kimball I'd be amazed if there were a class that meets for 90 minutes every day, let alone one that meets for 3 hours every day. A single 3-hour meeting per week is pretty typical (the vast majority of my upper-level undergrad classes, being cross-listed with graduate classes, had this schedule.)

Comment: Well, you may ask, but don't push too hard. You're way too late, and your reasons are sounding a bit selfish. Honestly, on your shoes, I'd rather ask for a longer break (or maybe starting later?).

Comment: Try, but don’t expect the favorable results. Nobody cares for a single student opinion. I teach 4hrs classes from 6-10pm, and nobody complains. My students and I come after full work day on Friday. Just get yourself together and do what you got to do.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Academic timetabling is a notoriously difficult problem. Professors have several classes to teach, students have several classes to attend. There are restrictions related to classroom sizes, specific equipment (e.g. computer labs). Some professors may have individual restrictions, e.g. can only teach on specific days or hours due to other commitments.

Normally, Professors do not decide their own timetables, but submit their preferences to the Timetabling Office, which then generates a timetable for everyone. Students can also try to submit their requests, but usually as a groups (cohorts), not individually. If you are not happy with your timetable, it is definitely worth trying to change it, but bear in mind that it may not be easy.

However, if you class is scheduled up until 9pm, which is significantly beyond the core hours, you actually have a much better chance of having this class rescheduled, particularly if any of other students attending the same late class have caring responsibilities. Your Student Rep / Student Union Rep / Athena Swan Rep (in the UK) might be able to help you with the process.

Comment: 'Normally, Professors do not decide their own timetables'  One consequence of this is that, for all we know, the professor may already have requested rescheduling of the late-evening class, and signs of a groundswell of student support may be just what s/he needs to get his/her request granted.

Comment: OTOH, at least in Europe, professors often do have certainly flexibility in setting the timetable (and now in distance teaching even more than usually). I really can't hurt to ask (but, as everybody says, don't get your hopes up - it seems highly unlikely that a class is scheduled to run into the night for no compelling reason at all, independently of who did the scheduling).

Comment: @xLeitix in parts of Europe perhaps. I teach in Europe, and I most definitely do not have flexibility in setting the timetable.

Comment: "beyond the core hours" really depends on the country. My university schedules tutorials up to 8:30pm on every day but weekends.

Comment: [Creating timetables is NP complete](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/np-complete-problems-why-we-have-self-driving-cars-plans-unni-koroth) - meaning it's a very hard problem and nigh impossible to fully automate, at least if you want optimal solution.

Comment: @JanDorniak Why would an administrator dealing with a complex task aim for the optimal solution? From my experience, they normally look for a solution, which meets the KPI and/or does not have obvious points which will be criticised by administrator's line manager. Beyond that - who cares? (normally)

Comment: @DmitrySavostyanov I just wanted to point out that timetables are mathematically proven to be hard to make ;)

Comment: @JanDorniak Sure, but the world consists mostly of non-mathematicians.

Comment: On day one of an 8:30 AM physics class (for physics majors, that's important later...) my prof. said "I'm teaching this class this year because the normal professor is on sabbatical. I'm NOT doing it at 8:30. I already checked, there are no required physics or math classes at 10:30, so I'm moving it to then. I'll have to ask the department chair for permission. Oh, wait. That's me. Permission granted!"

Answer (score 11):

Yes, you can ask.  However, it is likely that professors cannot change the schedule.  It is also quite possible that it is too late for anyone to change the schedule.  It depends on individual circumstances.

It would be normal for a three hour class to contain a rest break.  This may solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

4:30 pm is an odd time for an evening class to start; chances are that it was selected either specifically to fit into the professor's schedule, or specifically to allow motivated students to attend both the 4:30 class and a 6 pm class.

(For example, some students may find it far more convenient to travel to campus one day a week for a 6 hour session than to travel on two different days.)

In addition to asking if the classes can be rescheduled for your convenience, you might also ask if there other classes you can take towards your degree.

Comment: While I think the first session started at 8, not 9 as appears to be the case for OPs school, a significant minority of my undergrad classes were 80 (75?) minutes twice/week.  Typically these were Tuesday/Thursday classes that were small enough not to need a weekly breakout session with a TA.  I don't think all departments used them, but I generally had at least 1 of these a semester.

Comment: I had quite a few 4:30-to-6 classes that met twice a week. I think the 6-9 slot once a week was more common for classes with a signifiant graduate-student enrollment, but then again this was a school near a large downtown, so getting off work a little early twice a week for 10 weeks to take a class probably wasn't much of an issue.

Answer (score -2):

You can ask, but school room/building scheduling, other students preferences, prof's preference, and other factors will make you look silly and entitled.

If you did not like the schedule you should not have signed up for both of them if they ran back to back.

Comment: Asking doesn't make one look silly and entitled, throwing a hissy fit if the answer is no does.  Also, at many schools the schedule isn't set when you sign up for a course, it gets formulated based on the schedules of the faculty, resources, and students who signed up.